# Can we use standalone Spring Cloud Schema Registry with Confluent's KafkaAvroSerializer?

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-schema-registry, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a project using Spring cloud stream with Kafka Streams binder. For the output of a stream, I am using Avro, with the Serde provided by Confluent(`io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde`).

I am able to use it with the Confluent Schema Registry. Serialization and Deserialization takes place correctly.
However, I wanted to see if we can use the [Spring Cloud Schema Registry Server](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-schema-registry/reference/html/spring-cloud-schema-registry.html#_schema_registry_server) instead of the Confluent one. I configured a standalone Schema Registry server and set the schema registry in my project to it (changed the `schemaRegistryClient.endpoint` and `schema.registry.url` properties).

When I tried it out, it seems Spring Cloud is able to work with the standalone server. It registers the schema available in the resources folder as a .avsc file. However, when I send a message, it seems the Confluent serializer continues to approach it as a Confluent Schema Registry (which has different REST endpoints from Spring Schema Registry). As a result, it gets a 405 response code.

We get the following exception(partial stack-trace)

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema: <my-avro-schema>
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]; error code: 50005
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:230)
```

It seems to me that there are two possibilities:

1. Spring Schema Registry Server can work only with the content-type provided by Spring (specified as `content-type: application/*+avro`) and not with the native Serde provided by Confluent, or
2. There is an issue with the project configuration.

Can someone help me figure out which one is it? If it is the second one, can someone point out what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each schema registry provider requires a proprietary SerDe library. For example, if you would like to [integrate AWS Glue Schema Registry with Kafka](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/schema-registry-integrations.html#schema-registry-integrations-amazon-msk), then you would need Amazon's SerDe stuff. Hence, the Confluent's SerDe library expects Confluent's Schema Registry at the address specified in the `schema.registry.url` property.